# Shape error with maxloc

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have a problem with my code, where I want to find where the maximum value element of an array is.

```
double precision,dimension(1484,10,10) :: a
integer,dimension(1484)   :: ad1
```

Then I try:

```
ad1= maxloc(a)
```

I get the error

```
ad1= maxloc(a)
1
Error: Different shape for array assignment at (1) on dimension 1 (1484 and 3)
```

How should I define `ad1`?

Comment: yes, I want to find the single maximal element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MAXLOC(a)`, without a `DIM=` specifier, returns an array of rank 1 and size 3 (the rank of `a`).  You are trying to assign this rank 1 array to a rank 1 array of different size (1484).  From the error message you see these are the two numbers of note.

So, you want to declare `ad1` as

```
integer, dimension(3) :: ad1
```

[Note that if you have the compiler support the intrinsic `RANK` could be useful for general declaration.]

Alternatively, of course, you could declare `ad1` as in the question, but assign to only three elements of it.